# Laravel authorization - passing multiple values to a policy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a method that deletes a user from a company and would like to do a check to make sure the company will still have a admin left within it.

I'm using the method below, and the snippet is not working when adding a third parameter. How can I pass more than one variable to it?

```
$this->authorize('companyHasAdminAfterDelete', $privilege->company, $user );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just perform a simple check before deleting the user to check how many people with `admin` role are left?

If there's only one before `delete` then you know that probably he should not be deleted etc.